# Replace Zero with Blank in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

Is it possible to replace 0 with blank in ssrs matrix. The expression 
`=IIF(IsNothing(Count(Fields!referralNo.Value)),0,Count(Fields!referralNo.Value))`
is same as
`=Count(Fields!referralNo.Value)`.
When I try `=IIF(IsNothing(Count(Fields!referralNo.Value)),'',Count(Fields!referralNo.Value))` I'm getting error. Can somebody pls help!

Comment: Did you try with NULL ?

Comment: Yes, but error!

Comment: Count won't return Nothing, it will return 0. Also, what is your error?

Answer (score 17):

you could use text box properties and set show zero as: option to blank.

[image]

Comment: for Percentage option, how to set zero as empty space

Comment: check below @Rajkumar

Answer (score 2):

I use this expression for percentage data - I like code better than format, but they both work ;)

```
=iif(Fields!STUFF_PCT.Value>0,Fields!STUFF_PCT.Value,"")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this format `#,##0.00;-#,##0.00;""`

Comment: You probably should be more explicit